# Creating a sales rep role

Tags: user-roles

I am building a magento site to double as our order management system for our sales reps to take orders over the phone. On larger orders, our sales rep need to lower prices for bulk discounting and other reasons. These reasons are a case by case basis and not uniform enough to build rules on through product pricing.

Simply put, which permission do I give my sales-rep role in order to give them the ability to change the price of the item?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you create a role with all the items under the `Sales->Orders` role this should be enough for your case. The admin user should be able to set-up custom prices in the order create page.

Obviously the role should and can have more items set but I think these items should achieve what you need.

[image: Sales roles]

Comment: And also sales rep can customize the product price on order creation page as needed.